# Calculate the seconds while the app was in background

Tags: nsdate, nsuserdefaults, nstimeinterval

I am trying to find out the amount of time the app was in the background. Everything compiles fine, but my counter is not incremented with the amount of time the app was in the background.

```
  -(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    closeTime = [NSDate date];

    NSUserDefaults *defaultsCloseTime;
    [defaultsCloseTime setInteger:closeTime forKey:@"closeTimeKey"];
    [defaultsCloseTime synchronize];

}

-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    closeTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"closeTimeKey"];

    timeInterval = [closeTime timeIntervalSinceNow] * -100;

}


Counter
```

In my view controller:

```
counterInt = time + counterInt;
```

Comment: add `NSLog(@"Application Did Resign Active");` to make sure the method is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You should `synchronize` after writing the close time to user defaults.  Also in your question, where are you reading `counterInt` and are you storing it also to user defaults?

One more thing:

```
NSInterger time = round(timeInterval);
```

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed that synchronize. This still isnt working. I am getting no value at all for timeInterval